# Would there be value in allowing alternate question titles to improve searching and prevent duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I try hard to avoid creating duplicate questions on stack overflow, but every now and again I find that despite searching for questions on similar subjects and checking the "Questions that may already have your answer" list I create a question and then subsequently find that it does indeed already have an answer, but that answer is to a question with a title that contains a level of detail I wasn't yet aware of when I asked the question.  This is perhaps easier to grok with an example:

Today I was trying to work out how the Word Online (Office 365) web app opens a server copy of a Word document in a local copy of Word.  I did a lot of searching for questions with titles like "How to open a server's copy of a Word document in a local copy of Word from a web page?", "open Word from a web page" etc., as well as "open a locally installed app from a web page" and the like.

Now, the seasoned web programmers will already have spotted that potential answers to this are Application URL Protocols, but I'd never heard of those, so wasn't searching for them and so the search engine wasn't managing to find the question [Is there an Application URL Protocol for MS Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987005/is-there-an-application-url-protocol-for-ms-word)

Some other searching and discussion with a colleague finally led me to that question, but it occurs to me that there is no way for me to now add to that existing question and answer to improve the likelihood of someone else asking the more general sort of question I was starting with finding that very specifically worded question.  That seems like a lost opportunity in a way, I'd gladly add to an "alternate question titles list"  for the question if it would help improve the findability of the answer, and especially if it would increase the likelihood of the question appearing "Questions that may already have your answer" list.

It seems like that might reduce the number of duplicate questions in the long run as I'd imagine many of those are from people who are inexperienced in a particular area and don't yet know enough of the domain terminology to ask the question in the way it may have been asked and answered previously?

Comment: The entirety of a question doesn't need to be in its title.  The bodies of questions (and their answers) are searched too.

Comment: If your question is of good quality and offers different search terms for the original question, _it's a good thing for it to be a duplicate._ A good duplicate that uses different terms for the same thing makes searching for the original easier, turning the duplicate into a signpost for the original.

Comment: That's true @Servy. But, because the body doesn't show in the "Questions that may already have your answer" list I bet a lot of people just read down that list and think "nope, none of those exactly answer my question, let me feed yet another dupe into the system..."

Comment: @tomRedox Most of those people are going to ask the duplicate question even if the questions shown to them have literally exactly the same title that they're using in their own question.  You should also of course being doing lots of searching long before you even get to that point, and any search engine you use is going to be showing snippets of the question body that match your search terms.

Comment: @Kendra, I definitely agree with that in the case where I haven't found the answer, but in this case if I was to still post the question now somebody else would potentially then spend time answering it, when in fact I already know the answer exists.  Is there a way round that?  It would be sort of like posting a question and answer together in one go.

Comment: @Servy "Most of those people are going to ask the duplicate question even if the questions shown to them have literally exactly the same title that they're using in their own question", yeah, you're probably right, I am perhaps guilty of Friday afternoon optimism in this case!

Comment: Having question title synonyms could probably really help with being able to quickly find duplicate questions. There have been numerous times when I knew for sure that a question was a duplicate but it took me way too long to find the right one because it had a weird title or just not the keywords I would have expected it to have.

Also, if @tomRedox were to now intentionally ask a duplicate question with an easier-to-find title just to redirect it to the desired question, while being theoretically beneficial to the community it would still count towards a question ban for him (I believe).

Comment: I've found myself pining for such a feature when writing at least two of my self-answered questions. No point writing a canonical Q&A when the question can't even be easily found in a search in the first place.

Comment: Not sure why this suggestion is better than duplicates.